# Php If statment take lowest number if other are bigger than 0

Tags: php, mysql

At the bottom is my code.
I have database with 8 columns
SKU, Price 1, Price 2, Price 3, Lowest price, Qty 1 , Qty 2 , Qty 3

I want add some if statment to my script that will check three parametrs.
if qty>0

Curentlly I'm exporting lowest number from Price1-3 but its not checking is there any Qty more than 0.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    die(':)');
}

echo "Cron is running";

$hostname   = 'localhost';
$username   = 'user';
$password   = 'pass';
$myDatabase = 'database';
/**
 * Defines the name of the table where data is to be inserted
 */
$table = 'mytable';

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$myDatabase, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT mytable.SKU AS SKU,  LEAST(price, price2, price3) AS 'Lowest2'
    FROM mytable
    ");


    $stmt->execute();

    $filelocation = 'assets/exports/';
    $filename     = 'export-'.date('Y-m-d H.i.s').'.csv';
    $file_export  =  $filelocation . $filename;

    $data = fopen($file_export, 'w');

    $csv_fields = array();

    $csv_fields[] = 'SKU';
    $csv_fields[] = 'Lowest2';


    fputcsv($data, $csv_fields);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($data, $row);
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your query to something like:

```
SELECT mytable.SKU AS SKU, 
     LEAST(CASE WHEN qty  > 0 THEN price  ELSE 99999999999 END, 
           CASE WHEN qty2 > 0 THEN price2 ELSE 99999999999 END, 
           CASE WHEN qty3 > 0 THEN price3 ELSE 99999999999 END) AS 'Lowest2'
FROM mytable
```

I'm assuming all prices are less than 99999999999...